# Proving that the symmetric difference of sets is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I wanted to ask about this problem.

My book states:

> Let the *symmetric difference* be defined as $A + B=(A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$.

It proceeds to define a power set as

> $P_D= \left\{ A:A \subseteq D\right\}$

It then asks me to show:

> 1. Prove that there is an identity element with respect to the operation $+$, which is **______**.
> 2. Prove every subset $A$ of $D$ has an inverse with respect to $+$, which is **______**. Thus, $\left\langle P_D,+\right\rangle$ is a group!

Here's what I got:

1. Suppose $E$ is the identity set. We want to find $E$ such that $A + E=A$ (we don't need to check $E+A=A$ because $\cup$ is commutative--it will work). Hence $E=\varnothing$ because $(A\setminus \varnothing) \cup (\varnothing \setminus A) = A \cup \varnothing = A$.
2. Let $I$ denote the inverse set that satisfies $A + I = E$. The solution to $A+I=\varnothing$ is $I=A$. We can verify this: $A+A = ( A\setminus A)\cup(A\setminus A)=\varnothing$.

Obviously, in my answer I did not specifically prove that every **subset** $A$ **of** $D$ has an inverse. Since I do not know how to prove this, I cannot prove that "$\left\langle P_D,+\right\rangle$ is a group", as they asked.

How should I fix my proof?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to give an explicit construction for $I$. It looks to me like you know what it is, so I'm confused about where you are having difficulty?

Comment: Oh... wow. I just realized that since $I=A$ then $I\subseteq D$, so I actually did prove it for $P_D$. This seems very clear to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already solve the problem, this answer should play as a comment but I put it here for proper format.

$P_D$ can be identified with the set of functions
$$f:D\to \Bbb Z/2,$$
from $D$ to the integers mod $2$, where each subset $A$ is identified to its characteristic function $1_A$ such that $$1_A(a)=1\iff a\in A.$$
Then the operation $A+B$ translates to $1_A+1_B$ in normal sense.

It follows easily that

1. the identity is the zero function, i.e. the characteristic function of the empty set, and
2. the inverse of any function is itself.